# How to display post category inside page.php if else statement?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set up a few categories and want to display specific ones based on `is_page()`.

Inside `page.php`, I've created an `if..else` statement that checks the page name and prints out the specific category. My problem at the moment is that instead of just `the_title` being printed out the whole post is being printed.

Where am I going wrong with this?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php if ( is_page( 'Greywater Recycling' ) ) { ?>
<div class="col">
    <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Greywater Recycling&posts_per_page=5'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php } else if ( is_page( 'Stormwater Management' ) ) { ?>
<div class="col">
    <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Stormwater Management&posts_per_page=5'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php } else if ( is_page( 'Rainwater Harvesting' ) ) { ?>
<div class="col">
    <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Rainwater Harvesting&posts_per_page=5'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Many* problems with your code. For one, **`is_page`** [*does not work*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) inside the loop.

Second, don't mess with `query_posts`: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615). Really, forget about it for secondary loops.

Your code can be simplified to the following. In `functions.php`, we drop one function to get the Category ID by its Name. And another to do a secondary loop using the ID. And then, in `page.php` a simple call to those functions.

**Documentation: [Class_Reference/WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).**

#### `page.php`

<sup>*Notice that you don't need to open PHP tags at each line, that makes the code dreadly difficult to read.

Use it only to swap between PHP and HTML*</sup>

```
<?php 
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); 

// This page title
$the_title = get_the_title(); 

// Search for category with the same name of the page
$category = brsfl_get_category_id( $the_title );

// Category found, go to the secondary loop
if( $category ) {
    brsfl_check_print_categories( $category );
}
```

#### `functions.php`

<sup>*Always prefix your function names with something distinctive to avoid conflicts that may take the site down.*</sup>

```
/**
 * Get the category ID based on its name
 */ 
function brsfl_get_category_id( $cat_name )
{
    $term = get_term_by( 'name', $cat_name, 'category' );

    // term found, return its ID
    if( $term ) {
        return $term->term_id;
    }

    // not found
    return false;
}

/**
 * Print a loop based on a category ID
 */     
function brsfl_check_print_categories( $cat_id )
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) 
    { 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
        endwhile;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'No posts found...';
    } 
}
```

---

Although I've answered within the proposed scope, I think there are better solutions to this, like:

- a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), just adapt the functions.
- using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to show a meta box where you can select a very specific category (don't relying in page and category names) and use only the `WP_Query` function to print it out in the template.

Comment: wow this is so much better, thanks for the resources. i'm going to read up on these now!!

Comment: in a different section I use:

<?php query_posts('category_name=Greywater Recycling&posts_per_page=5');
         if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

can this also use this function?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better to get the category by the slug name.
i've tried your solution, it works fine but in the case of one of my category has a name with special html characters like apostrophes or quotes it doesn't.

here is the piece of code edited from your solution :

**in your functions.php**

```
    function brsfl_get_category_id($cat_name){
      $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $cat_name, 'category' );
      if( $term ) {
        return $term->term_id;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

**in your page.php**

```
    $the_slug = get_post(get_the_ID())->post_name;
    $category = brsfl_get_category_id( $the_slug );
    if( $category ) {
      brsfl_check_print_categories( $category );
    }
```